# Highstock multiple series irregular time

Tags: highcharts

I had a problem with the irregular point by time as shown below. As some of the data wasn't recorded at the same point of time is there anyway to show all my data at a estimated point.

http://postimg.org/image/6cr7ktqln/

I doesn't have enough reputation to post images so I use the above link

Answer (score 0):

The highcharts library has no "estimation" algorithm, so you need calculate these points on your own in the preprocessing.